# Why doesn't Eclipse code assist on certain items?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

```
a="hello";
b=a.sub();
document.write(b);
```

My eclipse won't code assist when I write this JavaScript code.

it's the `sub()` part. When I enter

```
b=a.s
```

and I press ctrl+space, it brings nothing. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't have enough information to provide code completion for JavaScript because JavaScript is an interpreted, dynamically typed language. It has no way of knowing what methods are valid for your `a` variable after you type that dot.

Comment: It would have enough information for literals though (but still does not complete). It would be a nice feature. If I knew that I was working with a string or regexp or whatever, just type a quick literal ("" or // or ...) and have a handy reference. Then just delete the preceding chars and continue.